# Error code:1215. cannot add foreign key constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table that has a column named 'status' which has foreign key in 'members' table named 'status'. 
I am getting the following error: cannot add foreign key constraint.
Please correct me. Members table contains: id, status, name and member_id

```
  CREATE TABLE `status_logs` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `element_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `status` varchar(1) NULL,
    `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `status` (`status`),
    KEY `element_id` (`element_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `status` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `members` (`status`),
    CONSTRAINT `element_id` FOREIGN KEY (`element_id`) REFERENCES `members` (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=129 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Please post the structure of your `members` table

Comment: Members table contains:  id, status, name, member_id

Comment: The rules for creating a foreign key can be found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Please publish your members table.

Comment: According to the manual, you need to have indices on the referenced columns - is this the case for `members.status`?

Comment: Yes, this is the case for members.status.